How to get prices of locked assets using python-binance?
This code shall return a list of balances.
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
account_balances = client.get_account()["balances"]
wallet_coins = [balance for balance in balances if float(balance['free']) > 0 or float(balance['locked']) > 0]

for coin in wallet_coins:
   asset = coin['asset']
   free_balance = coin['free']
   locked_balance = coin['locked']
   print(f"Asset: {asset}, Free: {free_balance}, Locked: {locked_balance}")

Expectation: All positions are correct.
Result: All my locked positions are displayed as zero (On the Binance web page, they are displayed correctly.
Asset: LDATOM, Free: 0.12485302, Locked: 0.00000000
Asset: LDSOL, Free: 0.14696155, Locked: 0.00000000
Asset: LDAPT, Free: 0.34394733, Locked: 0.00000000
Asset: LDSUI, Free: 0.63988096, Locked: 0.00000000


The method is called get_simple_earn_locked_product_position()
client.get_simple_earn_locked_product_position()

gives me the desired results
